# Magnifing glass in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, zooming, magnify

How can I create a non-circular magnifying glass in WPF? This has to work on controls not just an image.  Every example I find online is either circular only or only works on images.

For example I have a slider, and I'd like to turn the thumb into a rectangular magnifying region to show enlarged ticks (as my ticks are displayed in the Slider track itself, not below it).  I have created all the styles necessary I am just missing the ability to magnify contents underneath the thumb (as the thumb sits on top of the controls / display)

```
<Slider Ticks="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Just make one. You could use a `VisualBrush` with a `Visual` property taken from the source (that you want to magnify) painted on a plain `Rectangle`. Why can't you follow your found tutorials, but just use a `Rectangle` instead of an `Ellipse`? See the [Using VisualBrush to Show a Magnifying Glass](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/05/29/magnify) page on Ian G on Tap as an example.

Comment: @Sheridan Very good point, I got lost in a sea of examples and couldnt see decent ones.  I am part implementing this and have come to the Visual property assignment, can I do this in xaml via something like this (its not working atm) `<VisualBrush ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,50,50" ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" Viewport="0,0,1,1" Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}}" />`

Comment: I can't see how it could be a good idea to use an ancestor control of the `VisualBrush`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to just make your own 'magnifying' control. You could use a `VisualBrush` with a `Visual` property taken from the source (that you want to magnify) painted onto a plain `Rectangle`.  See the [Using VisualBrush to Show a Magnifying Glass](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/05/29/magnify) page on the *Ian G on Tap* website as an example.

Better yet, here is a very simple example of a `VisualBrush` that is painting a `Rectangle` in the right column of a `Grid`, magnifying an `Image` from the left column of a `Grid`. You can tweak it to your liking:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Name="Image" Source="Images/BlackLogo.ico" Width="150" Height="150" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ., ElementName=Image}" 
                Viewport="50,100,300,300" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

[image]